# Plotting a function with large negative exponents

Tags: plotting, numerics, numerical-value

I am trying to plot the function:

f(x)=(1-exp(-Vx^m))/(1-(1-x^m)^V)-1

for various values of $V$ and $m$ ranging from 1 to 30, and from $0\leq x\leq1$. How can I avoid numerical evaluation errors near zero? I've tried:

```
LogLinearPlot[(1-Exp[-4*x^6])/(1-(1-x^6)^(4))-1,{x,10^-6,1},PlotRange->{-1,1}]
```

But get warnings and an oscillatory behavior of the plot which I am not sure is correct, because the limit of the function is 0 at $x=0$.

Comment: Maybe: `LogLinearPlot[
 Piecewise[{{0, 
    0 < x < 10^-3}}, (1 - Exp[-4*x^6])/(1 - (1 - x^6)^(4)) - 1], {x, 
  0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1/10, 1/10}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is numerically ill defined around zero. But you  may replace the function by a limit. And you need to increase the working precision

```
f[x0_] := Limit[(1 - Exp[-4*xx^6])/(1 - (1 - xx^6)^(4)) - 1, xx -> x0]
LogLinearPlot[{f[x]}, {x, 10^-6, 1}, PlotRange -> {-.1, .1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The limit did the trick. One follow up, out of curiosity. I actually want to plot multiple values of V, so I do, for example for m=6:
    f[x0_, V0_] :=  Limit[(1 - Exp[-V0*xx^6])/(1 - (1 - xx^6)^(V0)) - 1, xx -> x0] 
    Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, V], {V, 2, 10, 2}], {x, 0, 1},  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

The composite plot is correct, because it looks the same as if I do each plot individually. However, the warnings are back (not a big deal, just curious as I said). Any idea why?

Comment: I can  only guess. But if you call  f[x,V] with  symbolic parameters, the limit can fail. And `Evaluate@Table[f[x, V], {V, 2, 10, 2}]` calls f[x,V] with symbolic `x`. This happens also with `Plot[f[x,4],...]` because  `Plot`has the attribute `HoldAll` and tries first to simplify the given function symbolically. Therefore, to be on the safe side, declare:  `f[x0_?NumericQ, V0_?NumericQ] :=...`